# Center text in an li element

Tags: html, css

[image: disagree/agree]

In the example picture the words Totally disagree and Totally agree are centered. Do I have to make 4 differents div's with 0 margin to achieve this? Or can I do it in 1 div?

```
#answersTop {
 float: right;
 clear: both;
 width: 400px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
 background-color: #3d569d;
}
#answersTop li {
 float: left;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.aFirst {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.aMiddle {
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.aLast {
 margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 10px;
}


<div id="answersTop">
        <ul>
            <li class="aFirst">Totally disagree</li>
            <li class="aMiddle">Disagree</li>
            <li class="aMiddle">Agree</li>
            <li class="aLast">Totally agree</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean vertical align?

Comment: you can achieve this with single div...

Comment: It is possible to do this with one div.
But really, if you want a better answer show some code.

Comment: Please put your code here...

Comment: Edit: put my code in the begin text

Comment: @Jnb Please check my answer in demo1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this  `give` `text-align:center;` in `li tag`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pG4zb/2/)**

css

```
   li{
    display:inline-block;
      padding:20px 20px;
    background-color:red;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;

}
```

===========================================================================

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/9sp5r/)**

**css**

```
#answersTop {
 float: right;
 clear: both;
 width: 400px;

 margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
 background-color: #3d569d;
}
#answersTop ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#answersTop li {
 float: left;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 5px;
    list-style-type:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
#answersTop li span{
    display:block;
}
.aFirst {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.aMiddle {
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.aLast {
 margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Was it really necessary to put  list-style-type:none here?

Comment: no if you dont write list-style-type:none so just bullets commings (means black dots comming) so its remove to use list-style-type:none;

Answer (score 0):

You can center it in your `li`-elements with `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `text-align`. Use the display property of the li tags instead. See demo http://jsfiddle.net/DWFLA/

Comment: Thanks but the words still dont align under each other

Comment: @Jnb - *under each other*?! Srsly, dude, you gotta explain better what you are tryin' to achieve and what code you have now.

Comment: Code is in begin post.. @AntonMelnikov as you can see in the begin post the words "Totally agree" and "Totally disagree" align under each other

Comment: Well, it wasn't there at that moment~

Answer (score 0):

This is an exemple with ul li structure with some CSS :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            ul li {
                display: inline;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Totally disagree</li>
            <li>Disagree</li>
            <li>Agree</li>
            <li>Totally agree</li>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```